# How to check if a small tensor is inside anthor large tensor

Tags: pytorch

```
a = torch.tensor([[1,1],[2,2]])
```

I want to know if `tensor([1,1])` is inside in a (return one bool)

```
a.eq(torch.tensor([1,1]))
tensor([[ True, True],
[False, False]])
```

–> which should return a True to my case.

```
a.eq(torch.tensor([1,2]))
tensor([[ True, False],
[False, True]])
```

–> which should return a false to my case.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you specify the version and add more context (creation of a object for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert it to a list and then check via `in` operator:

```py
p = torch.arange(1, 5).reshape((2,2))
k = torch.tensor([1,2])
v = torch.tensor([1,3])

>> k.tolist() in p.tolist()

True

>> v.tolist() in p.tolist()

False
```

Or if you want to do it via `torch` only

```py
torch.count_nonzero(k==p, 1) == len(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`torch.BoolTensor.all`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.BoolTensor.all) and [`torch.BoolTensor.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.BoolTensor.any)

```py
a = torch.tensor([[1,1],[2,2]])
b = torch.tensor([1,1])
c = torch.tensor([1,2])

a.eq(b).all(dim=1).any()
tensor(True)

a.eq(c).all(dim=1).any()
tensor(False)
```